# Spigot Plugin, nobody on Server

Tags: plugins, minecraft

I try to make a spigot plugin that can detect if nobody is on the server. I need this for a timer, if nobody is on the server, it should stop the timer and save the time of the timer in a text file. Is there any way I can do this with a plugin.
Thanks for every help, Aaron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to create text files:

```
        try {
            File file = new File(Yourplugin.getPlugin(YourPlugin.class).getDataFolder().getPath(), "filename.txt");
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException exception){
            System.out.println(exception.toString());
        }
```

How to read from text files:

```
        File file = new File(YourPlugin.getPlugin(Yourplugin.class).getDataFolder().getPath(), "filename.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = br.readline(); //can be null, if nothing is in file
```

How to write to Files:

```
            File file = new File(YourPlugin.getPlugin(Yourplugin.class).getDataFolder().getPath(), "filename.txt");
            BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            br.write("yourtime");
```

You should make a try catch construction in every example like in the first one.

Answer (score 0):

See [`Bukkit#getOnlinePlayers();`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/Bukkit.html#getOnlinePlayers()) and check if it is empty. You can check when a player disconnects from the server, or you can do a repeating scheduled task.

To save the timer in a yml file, use YamlConfiguration. See here for more details : https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/config-files/#creating-the-file

If you need more help (and a quicker answer, probably) you can add me on discord: Pierre#7757. I'll edit this comment if we find any good solution.